# openshift received smart shutdown request

Tags: postgresql, openshift

I unexpectedly got 500 Internal Server Error and I do not know why. My error logs:

postgresql.log:

```
2015-05-02 12:47:23 GMT LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2015-05-02 12:47:33 GMT FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2015-05-02 12:48:00 GMT FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2015-05-02 12:48:04 GMT FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2015-05-02 12:48:04 GMT FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2015-05-02 12:48:05 GMT FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
2015-05-02 12:49:07 GMT LOG:  shutting down
2015-05-02 12:49:07 GMT LOG:  database system is shut down
2015-05-02 12:49:11 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Permission denied
2015-05-02 12:49:11 GMT LOG:  trying another address for the statistics collector
2015-05-02 12:49:11 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Cannot assign requested address
2015-05-02 12:49:11 GMT LOG:  disabling statistics collector for lack of working socket
2015-05-02 12:49:11 GMT WARNING:  autovacuum not started because of misconfiguration
2015-05-02 12:49:11 GMT HINT:  Enable the "track_counts" option.
2015-05-02 12:49:11 GMT LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-05-02 12:49:07 GMT
2015-05-02 12:49:11 GMT LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2015-05-02 12:50:04 GMT LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2015-05-02 12:50:04 GMT LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

python.log:

```
- - - [02/May/2015:08:49:02 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
[Sat May 02 08:49:04 2015] [error] [client 127.5.19.129] Script timed out before returning headers: application
82.29.167.9 - - [02/May/2015:08:48:59 -0400] "GET /stream/ HTTP/1.1" 500 621 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
- - - [02/May/2015:08:49:04 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
```

Comment: Is your application back up and running now? The virtual server your application is running on may have been restarted by OpenShift's operations team.

Comment: Yep, now it works fine. I have not noticed any similar errors. Post your comment as answer so I may close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your application back up and running now? The virtual server your application is running on may have been restarted by OpenShift's operations team.